# Converting time format with strftime and strptime

Tags: python, strptime, strftime

I have a csv file contains three column. First is the date in the format of `1/3/2018`. Second is time `10:00:00 AM`. Third is the temperature. Now I want to use `strftime()` to convert the `datetime` object to the format `"YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS AM"` and store a list of time that the temperature is over 80.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open("temp.csv") as csvfile, open('output.csv','w') as output_file: #types of file opened "wb": binary file
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csv_output = csv.writer(output_file)
    next(csv_reader, None) #skip header
    rows = [row for row in csv_reader if row[2] >= '80.0'] #if condition
    output = []
    for row in rows:
        date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y') # strp is a function under datetime. convert a string to a datetime object
        time = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S %p')
        output.append([date, time])
        date_str = date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') #strftime: convert datetime object into a string
        time_str = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
        csv_output.writerow([date_str,time_str])

print(output)
```

The current result is:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 0)], [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0)...
```

I expect the result to be:

```
[1/2/2018 10:00:00 ], [1/2/2018 11:00:00]....
```

Comment: At the moment you're appending the raw `datetime` objects to `output` rather than `date_str` and `time_str`. If you append these to output the print statement will be as expected.

Comment: change this row `output.append([date, time])` to `output.append([date_str, time_str])` and move it two rows down.
Looking at your expected result you probably want `output.append(date_str + ' ' + time_str)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
a = '1/3/2018'
b = '1:14:12 AM'
in_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%I:%M:%S %p").time()
print(in_time)
c = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%d/%m/%Y"), in_time)
print(c.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

Try This:

[Repl Link](https://repl.it/@rohitpandey1/ClumsyOffbeatEquipment)

Comment: HI there, why it shows type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'...

Comment: are you importing `datetime` and using it like `datetime.strptime/datetime.strftime`?

Answer (score 0):

While creating time, no date is specified, hence it takes 1900 jan.
Instead, you can do

```
date_time=datetime.strptime(row[0]+" "+row[1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
output.append([date_time])
date_str=date_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
time_str=date_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
csv_output.writerow([date_str,time_str])
```